# What's the deal with Puck's ear?

Tags: marvel, alpha-flight

Puck the diminutive member of Alpha Flight was always drawn by John Byrne with a misshapen right ear, resembling the cauliflower ear condition.

Was there ever a reason given in the comic as to what happened to his ear?

Did John Byrne ever mention why he chose to draw Puck this way?

Comment: Boxer ear.  One to many punches

Comment: http://www.internationalhero.co.uk/p/puck.htm states it as a boxing injury without giving any reference, so it might be fanon.

Comment: Does the answer below satisfy your question, or were you looking for additional information?

Answer (score 3):

**Puck's misshapen right ear is a real medical condition known as "cauliflower ear".**

---

[**Eugene Milton Judd**](http://marvel.com/universe/Puck_(Eugene_Judd)) was born in 1914 and enjoyed a promising career as a boxer & adventurer until being cursed by the evil spirit [Black Raazer](http://marvel.wikia.com/Black_Raazer_(Earth-616)) some time in the [WWII era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II). The curse froze Judd's aging, effectively making him immortal, but also magically compressed his large form into that of a small dwarf with unique abilities. He later joined [Alpha Flight](http://marvel.wikia.com/Alpha_Flight_(Earth-616)) using the codename "Puck".

According to [his page on the Marvel Wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/Eugene_Judd_(Earth-616)), Judd's [**cauliflower ear**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauliflower_ear) is a distinguishing feature, leading us to believe that it was present before his body was compressed into its current form. Since the condition is usually caused by a blood clot or similar injury, we can probably assume that Judd received the deformity as a result of his previous boxing career.

Although he is usually seen in uniform, Judd's out-of-uniform appearances have consistently shown his right ear to be deformed. When the curse of Black Raazer was lifted, Judd reverted back to his original form and aged several decades. However, his ear maintained its deformed shape, further insinuating that the cauliflower ear was a pre-curse condition:

[image]

For a real-life example of this condition, see UFC Fighter/Actor [Randy Couture](https://www.google.com/search?q=randy%20couture%20ear&tbm=isch). Couture has become somewhat famous for his cauliflower ear, a condition earned by years of abuse & damage to his earlobes. The condition is far more severe on his left ear, as seen below:

[image]